# Visual Studio 2010 Pro, not ending debug mode on application close

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

When I run my code within VS, when I enter certain methods, upon ending the application (closing the form) been debugged, VS does not end the debug session automatically forcing me to end it manually.

This doesn't always happen, the results are consistent with certain windows / classes loaded when the application is run within VS.

I want to know why this may be, I'm assuming its an indication of a file not been closed in my managed code or 'something' like that.

Why might this occur and how can I trace and fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen if your code keeps running after closing the window.

Pause the debugger after closing the window to find out what it's doing, then modify the code so that it stops running when you close the window.

Comment: Thanks. Although it becomes more cryptic now. I'm shown a 'No Source Available' window and there is no disassembly. odd

Comment: "External Code" in both. The thread is my EXE. And a "RunParkingWindow" which brings up similar issues on google. I'll see what I can dig up

Comment: Disable Just My Code in debugger options.  After that, look at other threads too.

Answer (score 0):

On Debug menu, click "Detach All".

Hope that helps!

## EDIT

Follow, SLak's advice, as that will go after the problem.  My solution may only fix the symptom.  I will leave the answer here just in case it is helpful to you though.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, indeed I have no issue getting out of it.

Comment: That will leave the process running; you will not be able to rebuild until you kill it manually or until it naturally terminates.